# multiple file uploads using Jquery file uploader

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, blueimp

I am uploading multiple files using jquery file uploader.
server is django
I am able to upload the files to server, I want to display the uploaded files and give options to user to delete or add more files.

Please help me.

my code is:

media.html

```
<div id="tab-file_upload" class="tab-pane">
                        <div class="control-group" id="file_upload1" >
                          <label class="control-label">Upload Asset</label>
                          <div class="controls">
                            <input class="file_upload1 multi" type="file" name="file_upload1" multiple>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

media.js

```
this.$el.fileupload({

      url: this.model.url(),
      headers: { 'X-CSRFToken':  window.csrf_token },   
      formData: form_data,     

      progressall: function(e, data) {

        if (data.loaded && data.total) {
          return (_this.$('.progress .bar')).css('width', "" + (data.loaded / data.total * 100) + "%");
        }
      }
    });
    //var fileList = $("#file_upload1").prop("files");
    var fileList = this.$("[name = 'file_upload1']").prop("files");
    save = this.$el.fileupload('send', {
      files:fileList 


    });
```

Comment: What you have tried? Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing a few days ago then I found django-jfu plugin.  It allows user to add/delete/preview files.  Check out the demo [here](http://djfu-demo.cidola.com)!  It is cool.